# Facebook in app purchase failed reason

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I have a Facebook application where users can buy credits.

Sometimes,I get from Facebook response, in app purchases failed.

I would like to know the reason.

Also I would like to know what was the payment method, was it Paypal, credit card, mobile?

As you can see i attached an example : "status":"failed".

This is the response i get from Facebook.

Thanks,

[image: Facebook response]

Comment: Only Facebook will be able to give you these details... I don't believe that the users of [so] have access to this data :) [so] doesn't operate as Facebook's customer support.

Comment: I am having similar responses from Facebook. Some of the users that were buying our products on a regular basis, now tend to fail all purchases after the new local payment system. The worst thing is that we don't know why. Unfortunately, Facebook customer support never responds on these important issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately No one has ever answer the question and suddenly i got a response from Facebook,

The status failed by Facebook means that the credit card company, Paypal or mobile provider failed to charge the user.

Facebook are Currently not sharing the payment method to the application.

Thanks for trying to help.